# Remove CodeIgniter comment in top of view HTML

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a question. I noticed that CodeIgniter systematically adds the following comment to the top of all views:

```html
<!--
   local address: http://localhost/...
-->
```

I would rather have it not do this. I'm using a controller to fetch a dynamic image from a database and want to return a HTTP packet with an image/jpg content-type containing it. In the controller, I set this HTTP header and echo the fetched raw image back to the browser. But if I go to the controller in my browser it says that the image contains errors and could therefore not be shown. I suspect that this is because the comment CodeIgniter adds at the top of the controller output messes this process up. Echoing the content of the image with the Content-Type header set in a plain PHP script works fine.

This is the image fetching code:

```
 public function loadProfilePicture ( ) {
     header ( "content-type: image/jpeg" );

     $names = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc ( 3 );

     foreach ( $names as $namesKey => $name ) {
         $names [ $namesKey ] = str_replace ( '%20', ' ', $name );
     }

     $this->db->select ( "ProfilePicture" );
     $this->db->from ( "Caregiver" );
     $this->db->where ( "FirstName", $names [ 'FirstName' ] );
     $this->db->where ( "LastName", $names [ 'LastName' ] );

     $query = $this->db->get ( );
     echo ( $this->db->last_query ( ) );
     $queryResults = $query->result ( );
     echo ( $queryResults [ 0 ]->ProfilePicture );

 }
```

The ProfilePicture column has the type LONGBLOB and contains a JPEG image. The data in the column was originally obtained with a call to file_get_contents() on a temporary of an uploaded file.

If anyone has a suggestion as how to disable the comment CodeIgniter generates or how to solve the problem of the errors in the image in another way, I would be very grateful.

Best regards and thanks in advance,
Joshua

Comment: I have never seen this before. What version of ci are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.6.

I'm fairly certain it is an issue with CodeIgniter, because if I place a PHP-script outside of the CodeIgniter directories the behaviour does not occur. I don't think it has anything to do with a .htaccess inside of the folders.

Comment: I'm using the same ci version and I've never seen or heard about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how it got there, but the comment in my HTML was actually inside of the index.php in my CodeIgniter root directory, before the PHP script tag. Removing it and saving the file solved my issue.

A quick check on their GitHub indicates that, at least for CodeIgniter 3.2.0-dev, said comment is no longer part of index.php.

Comment: Good to hear you found it :)